# Set class instance as nested attribute of itself - is that really legal in Python

Tags: python

For twisted reasons which I think are irrelevant here, I find myself wanting to set a Class instance as a (nested) attribute of itself:

```
Class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        # ... lots going on...
        self.some_dict = {
            # lots of stuff,
            'myself': self
            }
```

Python hasn't complained.
- Is this really legal?
- Are there some unintended effects I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is legal (though not typical).

The only side-effect is that deallocation will be delayed until the garbage collector runs (the reference cycle prevents the usual immediate deallocation when there are no external references).